# Issues with mysql large-pages option

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

so i'm running CentOS 6, and after enabling large-pages in mysql, i restart the service and get this, and mysql fails to start:

```
kernel:Oops: 0003 [#1] SMP
kernel:Stack:
kernel:Call Trace:
kernel:Code: 00 e8 53 4f 02 00 48 89 c7 e8 0b f1 ff ff 48 8d 7d e0 48 89 45 e0 48 89 5d e8 e8 60 fe ff ff bf 01 00 00 00 e8 aa f7 ff ff eb 03
kernel:CR2: ffff8800dc2fe330
```

After removing the offending line from the config file, I still have to reboot before it'll start again. Thoughts?

Comment: This seems more like a server fault (http://serverfault.com/) question than a stack overflow question. you might have better luck asking it there.

Comment: Run `dmesg`, there are some more logs over there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable large pages as described here?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/large-page-support.html

An easy way to check is:  cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'Huge'

In addition via sysctl the following should be set

vm.hugetlb_shm_group=27

(If 27 is the ID of user mysql)